# JavaScript not recognize Lambda expression function visual studio 2013

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013

As you can see below,i am using lambda expression to declare function in `javascript` file
but it gives me syntax error and says its not a valid syntax,Where i am wrong?
[image]

Comment: Could you add your actual environment and versions?

Answer (score 2):

VS2103 is rather old, and doesn't recognize new ECMAScript6 features.

In the end, it doesn't matter. Visual Studio does not compile or run your JavaScript code. As long as your target browser accept this code, then that's what matters.

Though it is irritating the the editor is wrong.